# Trying to start a vncserver that points to a custom xstartup

Tags: redhat, vnc

I'm using TigerVNC, trying to point to specific xstartup because I will need several unique startups for a given user. This is what I'm trying:

```
vncserver :5 -name "MyServer" -geometry 600x320 -depth 24 -AlwaysShared -fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc,/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1,/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi -IdleTimeout 0 -SecurityTypes VncAuth -rfbauth /home/frogger123/.vnc/passwd -xstartup /home/frogger123/.vnc/mystartup
```

I am consistently getting

```
Unrecognized option: -xstartup
```

The docs on the TigerVNC page list this as a valid option. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

edit:From the manual :

```
vncserver [:display#] [−name desktop-name] [−geometry widthxheight] [−depth depth] [−pixelformat format] [−fp font-path] [−fg] [−autokill] [−noxstartup] [−xstartup script] [Xvnc-options...]        

−xstartup script

Run a custom startup script, instead of %HOME/.vnc/xstartup, after launching Xvnc. This is useful to run full-screen applications.
```

Comment: can you paste the relevant part of the manual? this option seems unknown to most internet pages

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sure, https://tigervnc.org/doc/vncserver.html

Comment: I mean: in the question itself [edit] it (my firewall is blocking the site for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong version of TigerVNC